# Determine Required Font / Text Size in R

Tags: r, graphics

Does anyone know how to determine what font size is necessary to fit a text item in a given location in R?

Right now I can change the fontsize and call strwidth/strheight repeatedly until the text size can fit, however this seems very inefficient.

Concrete example of what I am trying to do: I call draw.polygon with a specific height and width specified in native units, I then want to add text inside this box.  How can I do this?

Comment: you can calculate the ratio of the default text size to desired text size, and use this factor as cex.

Comment: but how to calculate said ratio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's an example,

```
require(grid)
grid.newpage()
g1 <- grid.rect(width=unit(2, "cm"), height=unit(1.5, "line"))
g2 <- textGrob("this has to fit")
w1 <- convertWidth(grobWidth(g1), "mm", valueOnly=TRUE)
w2 <- convertWidth(grobWidth(g2), "mm", valueOnly=TRUE)
ratio <- w1 / w2
grid.draw(editGrob(g2, gp=gpar(cex=ratio)))
```